# Get value inside the selected radio button

Tags: jquery

I have following ul li structure.

[image: ul li structure.]

When I click on submit button I need the value "6" inside class="question_choice".

I tried following code.

```
checkedElement = jQuery("#answers input[type='radio']:checked");
if (selected.length > 0) {
    selectedVal = selected.val();
}
console.log(selectedVal);
```

How can I get value "6".

Thank you.

Comment: the element with class `question_choice` is a `label` and therefor has no value. Try `.text()` instead. Be careful: You have two elements with this class. So you propably want to select the `.first()` one.

Comment: `checkedElement.closest("label.btn.active").next("label.question_choice").text()`

Comment: Thank you, this one helped. me.